# To pivot a table based on a specific event value using Query

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I want to make Table A like Table B.
I'd like to see what events the User caused before the Purchase event.
I've used `row_number() over (partition by client_id, event_type order by time)` and it's simply a pivot. How do I make logic?

Table A

```
client_id   event_type  count      time 
    A         cart        1     AM 12:00:00 
    A         view        4     AM 12:01:00
    A         purchase    2     AM 12:05:00
    A         view        2     AM 12:10:00 
    B         view        3     AM 12:03:00
    B         purchase    1     AM 12:05:00
    B         view        2     AM 12:10:00
```

Table B

```
client_id     view     cart   purchase 
    A           4        1        2     
    A           2        0        0
    B           3        0        1
    B           2        0        0
```

Comment: Why you have duplicate client ids in table A?

Comment: Client A has 4 views at 12:01:00 AM because they have seen the product 4 times before purchasing it at 12:05. And since client A saw other products twice at 12:10 (2 views), client A has another view (AM 12:10:00) later. @AminShojaei

Comment: Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, so I wrote that. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What about table B ? why duplicate ids in table B? I suggest you to rename your tables and a short description to them. Or at least write about the result you want to have.

Comment: As described in the above question, I want the sum of the remaining events based on the occurrence of the purchase event. I want the final result to be printed in Table B format. @AminShojaei

Comment: The purpose is to check the number of events before the user makes a purchase.

Comment: As I said: although Redshift is based on a (very, very) old version of Postgres, they are substantially different (e.g. for Postgres my answer would include a `filter (..)` operator to do that.

Comment: It's okay to answer either of course. Please give me some advice  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: an option i can think of is to define groups by saying any events before purchase shall all belong to one activity done by the user. I am able to get the expected output you have described in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing this, i define a group of events as belonging to a single "session/activity" before purchase using the block grp_split.

Then i get this grouping correctly done in the block x, by replacing null values with the previously not null value using the max(grp) over(partition by client_id order by time1) as grp2.

After that its a matter of pivoting the columns for view,cart and purchase

```
with data
  as (
    select 'A' as client_id,'cart'     as event_type   , 1  as count1, cast('AM 12:00:00' as time) as time1 union all 
    select 'A' as client_id,'view'     as event_type   , 4  as count1, cast('AM 12:01:00' as time) as time1 union all
    select 'A' as client_id,'purchase' as event_type   , 2  as count1, cast('AM 12:05:00' as time) as time1 union all
    select 'A' as client_id,'view'     as event_type   , 2  as count1, cast('AM 12:10:00' as time) as time1 union all
    select 'B' as client_id,'view'     as event_type   , 3  as count1, cast('AM 12:03:00' as time) as time1 union all
    select 'B' as client_id,'purchase' as event_type   , 1  as count1, cast('AM 12:05:00' as time) as time1 union all
    select 'B' as client_id,'view' as event_type   , 2  as count1, cast('AM 12:10:00' as time) as time1 
     )
   ,grp_split
   as(
select case when lag(event_type) over(partition by client_id order by time1)='purchase' 
              or lag(event_type) over(partition by client_id order by time1) is null 
             then
                 row_number() over(partition by client_id order by time1)
        end as grp
      ,*
  from data
      )
 select x.client_id
       ,max(case when event_type='view' then count1 else 0 end) as view
       ,max(case when event_type='cart' then count1 else 0 end) as cart
       ,max(case when event_type='purchase' then count1 else 0 end) as purchase
  from (
  select *
        ,max(grp) over(partition by client_id order by time1) as grp2
    from grp_split
       )x
  group by client_id
           ,grp2 
  order by client_id
```

**output**

```
+-----------+------+------+----------+
| client_id | view | cart | purchase |
+-----------+------+------+----------+
| A         |    4 |    1 |        2 |
| A         |    2 |    0 |        0 |
| B         |    3 |    0 |        1 |
| B         |    2 |    0 |        0 |
+-----------+------+------+----------+
```

working example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aeeb0878b9094e061c469bb0efb7a024

Comment: happy to help :-)